# R How do I form a matrix by using a loop to repeat function and binding each answer to the original function

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am new to programming so my knowledge is very limited at the moment but I am always looking to improve.

I have this function called gillespied detailed below to show the gillespie algorithm

```
> print(gillespied)
function (N, T = 100, dt = 1, ...) 
{
    tt = 0
    n = T%/%dt
    x = N$M
    S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
    u = nrow(S)
    v = ncol(S)
    xmat = matrix(ncol = u, nrow = n)
    i = 1
    target = 0
    repeat {
        h = N$h(x, tt, ...)
        h0 = sum(h)
        if (h0 < 1e-10) 
            tt = 1e+99
        else tt = tt + rexp(1, h0)
        while (tt >= target) {
            xmat[i, ] = x
            i = i + 1
            target = target + dt
            if (i > n) 
                return(ts(xmat, start = 0, deltat = dt))
        }
        j = sample(v, 1, prob = h)
        x = x + S[, j]
    }
}
```

And I use

`out = gillespied(LV,T=100,dt=1)`

I would like to create a matrix which corresponds to the first column of this `out` result, but then I'd like to repeat this out result a further 19 times (so I have 20 in total) and bind each result to my original matrix, this would give me a 20X100 matrix.

This is my attempt at it, and I'm not sure if it is correct as my R freezes when I try to view my matrix M

```
M=matrix(out[,1],ncol=1)
for (i in 1:19)  {
    out = gillespied(LV, T=100, dt=1)
    M = cbind(M,out[,1])
    i = i+1
}
print(M)
```

I was wondering if this is correct, and if it is not what adjustments I should be making

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increment i, the for loop does this for you.

E.g.

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(5), ncol = 1)
for (i in 1:5){

  out <- rnorm(5)
  M <- cbind(M, out)
}

> M
                        out         out        out        out        out
[1,]  0.21701968  2.0296134 -0.26425755  0.3904337  0.1438060 -0.5340556
[2,]  0.07689991 -2.0589758  0.01443763 -0.7506177 -0.8498391  1.0487328
[3,] -0.73329583  0.2709055  0.42298869  0.3271687  1.0450811 -0.9313009
[4,] -1.68460070  0.2864797 -1.83408494 -0.2878682 -0.4297308  0.5282630
[5,]  0.08921503 -1.4390101  0.89112111 -1.6711018 -2.0863797 -0.6924083
```

Something like i = i+1 is usually used in a while loop.  Otherwise your code appears to do what you want.

How big is your matrix?  It might struggle to print to console. What happens if you try `head(M)`?

Comment: Hey, my matrix is gonna be 20x100 as each column has 100 entries, and I'd like to repeat it 20 times, this could be the issue.